# Вывод самого старого человека из ООП (конструкция List)

Tags: java, ооп, list

> Задача: вывести самого старого человека из списка

> Код в ListMain:

```
public class ListMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User("Alex", 25);
        User user1 = new User("Mellon", 31);
        User user2 = new User("Jack", 19);
        User user3 = new User("Sam", 50);
        User user4 = new User("Ritz", 15);

        User[] users = new User[]{user, user1, user2, user3, user4};

        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Какой результат должен быть?

```
Самый старый человек: Sam
// Так как ему 50 лет и его возраст больше остальных.
```

> Ранее был выполнен задача тому кому больше 20 лет
> Вот код, но как вывести тому кто чей возраст больше всех не смог придумать:

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].getAge() > 20) {
                list.add(users[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Имя тех у кого возраст больше 20 лет: " + list.get(i).getFirstName() +
                    ", " + list.get(i).getAge() + " лет.");
        }
```

Comment: Вы максимум в массиве можете найти?

Comment: `stream().max(...)` и будет вам счастье :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно искать самого старшего пользователя во время итерации по массиву:

```java
User oldest = null;
for (User user : users) {
    if (user.getAge() > 20) {
        list.add(user);
    }
    if (null == oldest || user.getAge() > oldest.getAge()) {
        oldest = user;
    }
}
if (user != null)
    System.out.printf("Самый старший: %s, возраст: %d%n", 
        user.getFirstName(), user.getAge());
```

Если может быть несколько пользователей с наибольшим возрастом и нужно выбрать их всех, для этого следует завести отдельный список:

```java
List<User> oldestUsers = new ArrayList<>();
for (User user : users) {
    if (user.getAge() > 20) {
        list.add(user);
    }
    if (oldestUsers.isEmpty()) {
        oldestUsers.add(user);
    } else if (user.getAge() >= oldestUsers.get(0).getAge()) {
        if (user.getAge() > oldestUsers.get(0).getAge()) {
            // найден новый старейшина, очистить текущий список
            oldestUsers.clear();
        }
        oldestUsers.add(user);
    }
}
```

---

При помощи Stream API код будет гораздо лаконичнее при использовании `Stream::max` и компаратора по свойству `age`:

```java
User oldest = Arrays.stream(users)
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge))
        .orElse(null);
```

Для выбора нескольких пользователей, можно сгруппировать их по возрасту при помощи `Collectors.groupingBy` в отсортированную таблицу и взять последнее значение `TreeMap::lastEntry` из неё:

```java
List<User> olders = Arrays.stream(users)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            User::getAge, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()
         )) // TreeMap<Integer, List<User>>
        .lastEntry()  // Map.Entry<Integer, List<User>>
        .getValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].getAge() >= 50) {
                list.add(users[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Имя тех у кого возраст больше или равно 50 лет: " + list.get(i).getFirstName() +
                    ", " + list.get(i).getAge() + " лет.");
        }
```

Comment: тут проблема в том что если поменять значение 49, то не покажет)

Comment: но при изменении 49, должен показать тому кому 49. А в вашем коде только фокусирован кому больше или равно 50 лет